# installation path not found on PATH environment variable

Tags: macos, haskell-stack

I am trying to stack install a file on a mac terminal to complete a Haskell assignment but when I type in 'stack install' I'm met with 'Installation path my/path/ not found on the PATH environment variable. Could you tell me how I can resolve this?

The instructions for the assignment are to download the zip file, unzip and open a terminal within the file to stack install. this is not working due to the path environment problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.